# Giving Style to Modal Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I use this [dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default)
I would prefer ask my question with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97LXc/3/) but i haven't it worked in jsfiddle.
So i put here a [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo1/?url=dialog).

If i don't use `visibility:hidden;` in `#dialog` block, when url parameter isn't equal to 'dialog' #dialog div is shown in the page. But it has to be shown only if url=dialog
If i use `visibility:hidden;` content inside #dialog div isn't shown.

Also, I want it to be opened after 10 minute page load. Where will i put `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
function showdialog() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({width:500,height:240});
};

$(function() {
    var lockation = document.location.toString();
    if(lockation.indexOf("url=dialog", lockation.length - "url=dialog".length) !== -1)//check if url ends with 'url=dialog'
         setTimeout(showdialog, 1000);//call function with timeout
});
```

`$(function(){...})` - equivalent of [`jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (jQuery replacement for body.onload you are using)

Also, instead of `visibility:hidden` use `display:none`;

http://jsfiddle.net/97LXc/5/ demo of this (no url=dialog).

http://jsfiddle.net/97LXc/7/ url=dialog immitation

**UPD**
Well, once you already populate `onload="javascript:showdialog()"` on server depending on URL, no need to test url on client like I did that. 
Just instead of `onload` print

```
   $(function() {   
         setTimeout(showdialog, 1000);//call function with timeout
    });
```

right after `showDialog` definition

Comment: Thank you very much. But i have to use '<body onload' to check if there is a '$_SESSION[user]' because of don't show dialog to registered users. And i don't know jquery good enough to do this. I have to do it with php.

Comment: Just do it the same way. I guess you have something like: `<body <?php echo isset($_SESSION["user"]) ? 'onload="javascript:..."' :"" ?>`. Just move that IF little upper. And put it after showDialog definition. That is nothing to do with jQuery itself

Answer (score 1):

You should use display:none instead of visibility:hidden because visibility will keep your elements invisible.  Also you can put your setTimeout wherever you want depending on when you want it to start counting.  After dom ready? after window.load? etc

```
$(function(){ // this waits for dom to be ready
    setTimeout(showdialog,10000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQRVp/